# Qual a diferença entre sorted() e .sort()?

Tags: python, lista, tupla

Por que a função `sorted()` é considerada mais direta do que o método `.sort()` usado em listas com tuplas?

Comment: na verdade não é `.sort` que é considerada mais direta?

Comment: De acordo com meu professor, não.

Comment: A função sorted é mais direta caso queiras criar uma segunda lista com os valores da primeira, mas manter a primeira com os valores originais. Caso a intensão seja apenas ordenar a própria lista, a função sort é mais direta. A resposta do @lf-ziron mostra isso em exemplo

Comment: Muito obrigado, seu comentário me esclareceu bastante.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em sort você altera a lista em si, em sorted você tem um valor que pode utilizar em uma variável nova.

```
a = [2,1,3];
a.sort();
b = a; //a e b possuem o valor [1,2,3]
a = [2,1,3];
b = sorted(a); //a possui o valor [2,1,3] e b possui o valor [1,2,3]
```

Logo, não acredito que um seja mais direto que o outro, simplesmente depende de como você vai aplicar a ordenação, se você precisar manter o valor desordenado em algum lugar, use sorted, se o valor antigo não lhe interessar mais, utilize .sort()

Comment: Concordo que vai depender da utilização, mas na média sempre existe aquele mais simples e direto não é mesmo?

Comment: Bem, nesse caso acho que o sort é mais usado, uma vez que não é necessário guardar o valor anterior geralmente