# Erro ao utilizar append após juntar duas listas em uma

Tags: python, lista

Meu professor passou o seguinte problema a ser resolvido e traduzido para Python:

> Considere que tenhamos duas listas de nomes de pessoas, sedo que estas listas já estão em ordem lexicográfica (alfabética). Desejamos juntar estas duas listas numa única, mantendo a ordem alfabética.
>
> Nos dados de entrada, cada linha contém o nome de uma pessoa. Na primeira linha está o tamanho da primeira lista, seguida dos nomes das pessoas desta lista. Em seguida vem outra linha com o tamanho da segunda lista, seguida dos nomes das pessoas da segunda lista.

Para resolver isso, codifiquei:

```
def junta_listas(lista1,lista2):
lista3 = []
lista1 = lista1.split(' ')
lista2 = lista2.split(' ')
for nome1 in lista1:
    lista3 = lista3.append(nome1)
for nome2 in lista2:
    lista3 = lista3.append(nome2)

return lista3.sort()
a = input()
b = input()

print(junta_listas(a,b))
```

E o ambiente está me retornando o seguinte erro:

> lista3 = lista3.append(nome1)
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,
O problema ai são dois um deles é a identação mais imagino que seja na hora de colar o código que ela se perdeu, o outro é que o método `.append(foo)` é void então não existe a necessidade de `lista = lista.append(foo)` apenas `lista.append(foo)` o outro é que o método `sort()` também é void, então não existe como retornar o resultado dele o code fica mais ou menos assim.

```py
def junta_listas(lista1,lista2):
    lista3 = []
    lista1 = lista1.split(' ')
    lista2 = lista2.split(' ')
    for nome1 in lista1:
        lista3.append(nome1)
    for nome2 in lista2:
        lista3.append(nome2)
    lista3.sort()
    return lista3

a = input()
b = input()
print(junta_listas(a,b))
```

Answer (score 3):

Há muitas coisas que devem ser consideradas no seu código. Em resumo:

1. A indentação está errada, o que resultaria em erro de sintaxe neste caso;
2. Utiliza laços de repetição desnecessários;
3. Faz atribuições erradas em `lista3`;
4. Retorna `lista3.sort()`, sendo que o retorno deste método é `None` sempre;
5. O código não faz o que é solicitado;

Não responderei dizendo como resolver cada ponto separadamente, pois não é objetivo da comunidade dar esse tipo de suporte técnico e na documentação há bastante material para estudar e entender as diferenças entre o código da pergunta e a solução apresentada aqui.

> Considere que tenhamos duas listas de nomes de pessoas, sedo que estas listas já estão em ordem lexicográfica (alfabética). Desejamos juntar estas duas listas numa única, mantendo a ordem alfabética.

Esta parte do enunciado solicita que seja juntadas duas listas que já estão em ordem em uma terceira que também deverá estar em ordem alfabética. Para juntar duas listas basta utilizarmos o operador `+` e o método `sort` (ou `sorted`) para classificá-la alfabeticamente:

```
def juntar(lista1, lista2):
    lista3 = lista1 + lista2
    lista3.sort()
    return lista3
```

Leitura complementar:

- [Adicionar mais de um elemento ao Append é possível?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/365526/5878)
- [Qual a diferença entre sorted() e .sort()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126036/5878)

> Nos dados de entrada, cada linha contém o nome de uma pessoa. Na primeira linha está o tamanho da primeira lista, seguida dos nomes das pessoas desta lista. Em seguida vem outra linha com o tamanho da segunda lista, seguida dos nomes das pessoas da segunda lista.

Atenção ao trecho ***Na primeira linha está o tamanho da primeira lista, seguida dos nomes das pessoas desta lista***, ou seja, os nomes não estarão todos na mesma linha como você fez na pergunta, mas sim cada nome virá em uma linha diferente conforme a quantidade recebida. Assim, para obter as duas listas de nomes precisará fazer:

```
quantidade1 = int(input('Tamanho da primeira lista'))
lista1 = []

for i in range(quantidade1):
    lista1.append(input(f'Nome da {i+1}a pessoa'))

quantidade2 = int(input('Tamanho da segunda lista'))
lista2 = []

for i in range(quantidade2):
    lista2.append(input(f'Nome da {i+1}a pessoa'))

print(juntar(lista1, lista2))
```

Você pode fazer isso em uma função para deixar mais organizado e não repetir código:

```
def juntar_listas(a: list, b: list) -> list:
    return sorted(a + b)

def ler_lista_de_nomes() -> list:
    quantidade = int(input('Quantidade:'))
    lista = []
    for i in range(quantidade):
        lista.append(input(f'Nome da {i+1}a pessoa'))
    return lista

lista1 = ler_lista_de_nomes()
lista2 = ler_lista_de_nomes()

lista3 = juntar_listas(lista1, lista2)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/sopt-question-389074)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que se você usar:

```
lista3 = lista3.append(nome)
```

você na verdade esta recebendo um objeto NoneType na variável lista3. Isso acontece pois o método .append() é utilizado para incrementar a lista3.

logo basta utilizar.

```
lista3.append(nome)
```